# Replace a cellular shade fabric but use existing hardware?

Tags: repair, windows, blinds, cover

[Revised post]
I want to try to replace a shade and use the existing hardware.

But I am new to all things DIY shades (never installed a new one, let alone tackle a repair of new shade/old hardware).

The shade is a picture-window size, Levolor cellular duette. Due to the sheer size of the window, I'll find helping hands. I'll also do the research to find videos and such to do the work.

But are there nuances or surprises that I should be alert for? Or tips 2-N that will help me do a better job (because tip #1 is, I assume, go SLOW)?

Comment: VTC - Your question is basically a shopping question which is off topic here.  But that said consider an online order from a place like www.blindster.com where shades can be had for considerably less $$$ than conventional outlets.

Comment: @Michael Karas - comment noted, question revised. And blindster is, indeed, an excellent site.